# How does this operation on pointers work?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
  int x = 4;
  int* q = &x;                 // Is it always equivalent to int *q = &x;  ?
  cout << "q = " << q << endl; // output: q = 0xbfdded70
  int i = *q;                  // A
  int j = *(int*)q;            // B, when is this necessary?
  cout << "i = " << i << endl; // output: i = 4
  cout << "j = " << j << endl; // output: j = 4
```

My question is what does lines A and B do, and why the outputs are both 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  int x = 4;
```

x is 4

```
  int* q = &x;
```

q is *the memory location* of x (which holds 4)

```
  cout << "q = " << q << endl; // output: q = 0xbfdded70
```

There's your memory location.

```
  int i = *q; // A
```

i is the value at memory location q

```
  int j = *(int*)q; // B
```

j is the value at memory location q.  q is being cast to an int pointer, but that's what it already is.

Comment: Is `*(int*)q;` necessary in some circumstances? I can't think of one, but is wondering if there is such possibility.

Comment: `(int*)q` means "whatever q happens to be, I want to treat it like a pointer to an int".  It's useful when you want to do tricks with the bit layout of data.  Also, programs in the C language will often "hide" what a pointer is actually pointing to by casting it to (void*).

Comment: So in simplest terms, `(int*)q` would be necessary if `q` were **not** an `int *` already.

Answer (score 3):

It is a basic usage of pointers, in A you dereference pointer (access the variable to which a pointer points)":

```
int i = *q; // A
```

while B is doing exactly the same but it additionally casts pointer to the same type. You could write it like that:

```
int j = *q; // B
```

there is no need for (int*)

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = *q; // A
```

Dereferences a pointer to get the pointed value

```
int j = *(int*)q; // B
```

type casts the pointer to an `int *` and then dereferences it.

Both are same because the pointer is already pointing to an int. So typecasting to `int *` in second case is not needed at all.

Further derefenecing yields the pointed integer variable value in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Lines A and B are equivelent as q is already an int* and therefor (int*)q equals q. 
int i = *q; yelds that i becomes the value of the integer pointed to by q. If you want to make  i to be equal to the adress itself remove the asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

A: [Dereference](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/computing/d120/releases/R1.11/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/dereference.html) - takes a pointer to a value (variable or object) and returns the value

B: Cast to `int*` and than dereference

The result is the same because the pointer is already to int. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Line A takes the value that `q` points to and assigns it to `i`. Line b casts `q` to the type `int*` (which is `q`'s type already, so that cast is entirely redundant/pointless), then takes the value that q points to and assigns it to `j`.

Both give you 4 because that's the value that `q` points to.

Answer (score 0):

Line A de-reference pointer `q` typed as `int *`, i.e. a pointer points to an `int` value.

Line B cast `q` as `(int *)` before de-reference, so line B is the same as `int j = *q;`.