# What is the difference between a new pointer and a simple pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

What is the difference between these two declarations :

- `int *p = new int`;
- `int *q`;

Comment: Homework? One is initialised, the other isn't.

Comment: maybe i was unclear...what if i set *p = 8 and then *q = 8; dont i have the same result in the end?

Comment: @AntonisDouk nope the 1st is ok; the 2nd is Undefined Behaviour.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: The point is you should not do `*q = 8` unless it is initialized.

Comment: `q` is uninitialized and points to nowhere. You can't just write some value at some unknown memory address and expect it to work. Just because it appears to work once doesn't mean it always will or that it's correct.

Comment: ok got it thank you XD didnt know that just with int *q you dont initialise the pointer

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681536/how-does-this-operation-on-pointers-work

Comment: Useful reading: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers

Answer (score 1):

```
 int *p = new int;
 *p = 8;
```

The first statement declares a new variable `p` to be a pointer to `int` and initialises it with the address returned by `new int`, which is a valid memory address for storing an `int`. The second statement assigns the value `8` to the int at the memory address pointed to by `p`.

```
int *q;
*q = 8;
```

Now the first statement does not initialize the pointer `q`, which will hence have no meaningful value. The second statement then attempts to write to a memory address which in all likelihood is not an address where such an operation is allowed and as a result the program will crash (most likely with segmentation fault).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int *p = new int;
> ```

This is a declaration. It declares a variable of type `int *`. The name of the variable is `p`. The variable is copy-initialised with the expression `new int`.

> ```
> int *q;
> ```

This is a declaration. It declares a variable of type `int *`. The name of the variable is `q`. The variable is default initialised.